# Is there a way to not have a reference to EntityFramework in the WebAPI?

Tags: c#, asp.net, entity-framework, asp.net-web-api

I have a layered arquitecture [ WebAPI -> Logic -> Repository ], so the WebAPI doesn't know about the repository layer. I'm using Unity for dependency injection so there are no direct references to other layers.

[image: Layers]

The implementation of the Repository layer uses Entity Framework and EntityFramework assemblies are present in its "/bin/Release"

I have a project for each layer that handles registration of services with Unity, and EntityFramework assemblies are present in its "/bin/Release" too.

To load a dependency I load the registration project with Assembly.LoadFrom, and therefore it also loads its dependencies.

Unfortunately, this wasnt working. The DbContext constructor throws:

```
System.TypeInitializationException: 'The type initializer for 
'System.Data.Entity.Internal.AppConfig' threw an exception.'

FileNotFoundException: Could not load file or assembly 'EntityFramework, 
Version=6.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089' or one of 
its dependencies.
```

I tried copied the "configSections" and "entityFramework" to the WebAPI.config, even though I suspected it wouldn't work (it didn't).

What I get here, is the context does some kind of deferred binding so it looks in the WebAPI references for the asseblies. _Is there a way to use the ones in the registration or implementation projects instead?

I know installing EntityFramework in the WebAPI would work, but I don't want to do that. Is there another way?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found a way!

System.AppDomain.CurrentDomain.AssemblyResolve
System.ResolveEventHandler

I've registered a handler so when an assembly fails to load, if its EntityFramework, I use Assembly.LoadFrom

---

Update

Using code-based configuration (DbConfiguration) you can link the assemblies via code, and not with defer binding